# how to remove references in doctrine odm object

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

The problem is like this, i have two documents "student" and "school", in student, there's a field reference to school:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="school")
 */
protected $school;
```

and there's a student object, where the school field is referencing to a school object, i want to delete this reference, in the documentation of doctrine [odm documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#removing-references) said i can just do $student->setSchool(null), but when i do so i got an error

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Student::setSchool() must be an instance of School, null given,

Anyone has any idea? Am I misunderstanding the documentation or this is a different situation? Thanks!

Comment: Setting a `null` would work if your setter method accepts `null` as an argument, like `setSchool(School $school = null)` **and** your foreign key column is nullable as well.

Comment: @Artamiel Thank you! that solves my problem well, i would accept this if it is an answer. One thing though, the documentation saids about the nullable: "Specify true for this option to force ODM to store a null value in the database instead of unsetting the field.", my intention is to unset the field, so i'll just leave it as default

Comment: Yes, you have a point as well, since I have most experience with `ORM` rather than `ODM` so there tend to be some differences. I can merge my comment alongside yours to a answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So as stated in my comment, in order to store a nullable value, that *would* normally require the field to accept null as a value and also the argument passed to the setter method (if added) to accept `null`. As the @OP added, for `ODM` document there is something else to be considered:

> **nullable** - By default, ODM will $unset fields in MongoDB if the PHP value is null. Specify true for this option to force ODM to store a null value in the database instead of unsetting the field.

A reference for the provided quote from documentation - [@Field](http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#field)